# Sum of processes CPU is higher than the total CPU consumption shown in top/htop

Tags: linux, top

Why both `top/htop` as well as `/proc/stat` report so low CPU utilization? The process CPU utilization number (67.5% on the screenshot) seems to be correct.
[image]

From time to time I see expected results like:
[image]

**Some details:**
A Linux (kernel version 4.19.0) is running on the Zynq 7z010 (Dual core ARM Cortex-A9 processor). The signal processing application (`server.elf` on the screenshots) consumes most of the resources. Most of the processing occurs in two threads: one (`Receiver_0`) wakes every 10ms, the other (`Spectrum_0`) - every 17ms. Those threads are scheduled using SCHED_FIFO scheduler.

Comment: What's the sample period for your top and htop commands?  Once every two sections?

Comment: It is 3 sec. When I calculate CPU utilization in my program it reads data from the `/proc/stat` every second.

Answer (score 2):

I have found what is going on. Linux kernel documentation (https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/cpu-load.html) has explanation how the data shown in `/proc/stat` (`top`/`htop` use that data) is collected:

> Whenever timer interrupt is signalled the kernel looks what kind of
> task was running at this moment and increments the counter that
> corresponds to this tasks kind/state. The problem with this is that
> the system could have switched between various states multiple times
> between two timer interrupts yet the counter is incremented only for
> the last state.

As I said before in my case most of the data processing occurs periodically (every 10ms) in a short bursts (2..4ms is sufficient to finish data block processing). That behavior matchs the example (https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/cpu-load.html#example) - all processing is made between system state sampling, so the system thinks that it was in the idle state all that time:

```
 system state sampled in timer interrupt (10ms period on my system)
     |                                        |
     v                10ms                    v
...--|----------------------------------------|-------------------------...
           ^    3ms   ^             7ms             ^   3ms    ^
   sleep   |  active  |            sleep            |  active  |  sleep
...------> | <------> | <-------------------------> | <------> | <------...
```

I solved the problem by using `/proc/[pid]/stat` counters to calculate CPU utilization by the process that handles data processing (the same information shows `top` in the `%CPU` column), of cause other processes also use CPU, but in my case their CPU utilization is neglible.