# Why is it possible that the combined processes CPU usage is higher than the total CPU usage, as reported by top?

Tags: cpu, top, cpu-usage

When I check top, with a delay of 0.5 seconds, sometimes the total CPU state percentage is lower than the sum of the CPU usage of individual processes.

Here is an example, where that is observed:

```
top - 09:12:45 up 23:28,  1 user,  load average: 0.95, 0.34, 0.17
Threads: 173 total,   1 running, 172 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu0  :  2.1 us,  2.1 sy,  0.0 ni, *95.7 id*,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu1  :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni, *100.0 id*,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :   3865.6 total,   2371.1 free,    255.8 used,   1238.7 buff/cache
MiB Swap:      0.0 total,      0.0 free,      0.0 used.   3441.9 avail Mem



    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
   5527 mars      20   0  564188  22352  14556 S  *13.5*   0.6   0:21.67 /home/...
   5536 mars      20   0  564856  20548  15020 S  *11.5*   0.5   0:17.66 /home/...
   5367 mars      20   0   12900   3468   2880 R   *3.8*   0.1   0:03.07 ...
   5540 mars      20   0  564856  20548  15020 S   *3.8*   0.5   0:00.62 /home/...
   5544 mars      20   0  564856  20548  15020 S   *3.8*   0.5   0:08.58 /home/...
   5530 mars      20   0  564188  22352  14556 S   *1.9*   0.6   0:05.00 /home/...
   ...
```

In the last 0.5 seconds:

- adding individual processes CPU usage yields >=38.3% (13.5+11.5+3.8+3.8+3.8+1.9=38.3%)

  - I have configured top to operate in Solaris mode (where a task's cpu usage is divided by the total number of CPUs)
  - The platform I am using has two cores, so, even if I configured top wrong, I would get 38.3%/2=19.15%
- CPU 0 was only used 4.3%: 95.7 id% in idle
- CPU 1 was not used: 100.0% in idle

Why is it possible that the combined processes CPU usage is higher than the total CPU usage?

For context:

- I am using "performance" for the CPU frequency governor policy

  - /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor
- The processes am I running are ros2 nodes (a minimal publisher and a minimal subscriber)
- I am working with a computer with the following specs:

lscpu

```
Architecture:            aarch64
  CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
  Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                  2
  On-line CPU(s) list:   0,1
Vendor ID:               ARM
  Model name:            Cortex-A72
    Model:               3
    Thread(s) per core:  1
    Core(s) per cluster: 2
    Socket(s):           -
    Cluster(s):          1
    Stepping:            r0p3
    CPU max MHz:         1300.0000
    CPU min MHz:         300.0000
    BogoMIPS:            50.00
    Flags:               fp asimd evtstrm crc32 cpuid
NUMA:
  NUMA node(s):          1
  NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0,1
Vulnerabilities:
  Itlb multihit:         Not affected
  L1tf:                  Not affected
  Mds:                   Not affected
  Meltdown:              Not affected
  Spec store bypass:     Not affected
  Spectre v1:            Mitigation; __user pointer sanitization
  Spectre v2:            Mitigation; Branch predictor hardening
  Srbds:                 Not affected
  Tsx async abort:       Not affected
```

For more context

- I have tried stress tools (such as stress and stress-ng);
- When I run these stress tools (and nothing else, apart from top), the total CPU usage is very close to the usage I specify with the stress tool.

Comment: Did you add all processes or only the few shown? The output of `top` will be many more lines than what you have shown here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sum of processes CPU is higher than the total CPU consumption shown in top/htop](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/755881/sum-of-processes-cpu-is-higher-than-the-total-cpu-consumption-shown-in-top-htop)

Comment: @aviro: The post indicated by you did answer my question. The link https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/cpu-load.html - refered to in that post - does provide the real answer to the drescribed behaviour.

Comment: @MC68020: The post indicated by you did answer my question. The link https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/cpu-load.html - refered to in that post - does provide the real answer to the drescribed behaviour.